# How to get requst handler response type ='json in cakephp ?'

Tags: cakephp

```
CakePlugin::routes();
Router::setExtensions('json');
Router::parseExtensions('json');
```

in routes.php but still when I debug I get 'html' in response.

```
debug($this->RequestHandler->responseType());
```

Please help me out.

this is the error shows in console --->

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /cities/index.json was not found on this server.</p>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Where is that debug statment? If it's in beforeFilter() "html" is expected since RequestHandler set the response type in its startup() callback which runs after beforeFilter(). Also turn on debug, to get actual error instead of generic 404, perhaps some error is generated before RequestHandler::startup() can run.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with XML

You have to create a folder in your view folder for json (e.g View/Pages/json) and in there put your view file (e.g. news.json)

You can then do this before the end of your controller method to force response as json.

```
 $this->RequestHandler->respondAs('json');
```

Comment: Thats pretty 1.x there. In 2.x you usually don't need any view file anymore, the View classes are quite capable of outputting the desired result on their own. And with the right approach you don't need any additional configuration or header setup. See my answer above.

Comment: I tried that way for an RSS feed, but even with ParseExtensions I couldnt get it to return the correct response type unless I explicity set it, are there any specific gotchas with this? Id be interested in getting it working more efficiently!

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest approach when working with json/xml/csv etc always is, to actually use the extension to access the action.
Meaning:

```
/controller/action
```

should 404 if you do not want to provide a HTML version of this action.

And your methods should be accessed like this:

```
/controller/action.xml
/controller/action.json
```

This way, its not only clear what one can expect, you also invoke all the Cake magic, letting RequestHandler set the Xml or Json view class, responding with the appropriate headers etc. Everything out of the box.
You can also support multiple different formats this way without any additional overhead.

Also, you can easily set query strings:

```
/controller/action.json?foo=bar
```

Don't fight the framework :)